# ¿Cómo reducir código?

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código

Estoy tratando de reducir otra función, pero esta vez me quedé atascado. He aprendido bastante de la anterior pregunta, pero me falta imaginación (creo).

```
sndFrm() {
      var jotason = [];

      this.contentForm.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{
            let obj = {
               title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
            };

            let label = {};
            if(!form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[0]){}else{var tlbl = form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[0].innerHTML;};
            if(!form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[1]){}else{var plbl = form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[1].innerHTML;};
            if(!form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[2]){}else{var elbl = form.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd")[2].innerHTML;};

            let power = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.type=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.value=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-disAble.powr").forEach((input, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               if(input.getAttribute("data-disable")==1){
                  ob.disable=1;
               }else{
                   ob.disable=null;
                   delete(ob.disable);
               }
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            let energy = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.type=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.value=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-disAble.ener").forEach((input, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               if(input.getAttribute("data-disable")==1){
                  oj.disable=1;
               }else{
                   oj.disable=null;
                   delete(oj.disable);
               }
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            obj.T_label = tlbl;
            obj.P_label = plbl;
            obj.power = power;
            obj.E_label = elbl;
            obj.energy = energy;
            jotason.push(obj);

      });

      var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);

      this.txtare.value=jsoned;
   }
```

Teniendo la misma estructura repetitiva, cambian muy pocos valores:

```
form.querySelectorALL("input[name=<¿?>]").forEach((input, index)=>{
var ob = <¿?>[index] || {};
ob.<type/value>=input.value;
<¿?>[index]=ob;
});
```

Siempre se repite esta secuencia, salvo en la selección del class.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Porque todo lo que he probado hasta ahora va de error en error...

Comment: podrias colocar un ejemplo minimo verificable de tu codigo... no solo el `javascript`

Comment: Reducir código no necesariamente implica una optimización o mejora. Creo que "unificar" la asignación de eventos agregaría algunas condicionales que van a dificultar la lectura y, por lo tanto, también el mantenimiento. En este caso, la reducción no va a beneficiarte.

Comment: @Bryro, para poder hacer el ejemplo verificable de esta parte, tendría que colocar casi toda la máquina, solamente para intentar reducir el código. Es una estructura que se repite por sí misma.

Comment: Aun así @Triby, lo hago para aprender, no es un programa que necesite realmente. Simplemente estoy aprendiendo, y por eso necesito recopilar ideas y conocimiento. Lejos de que sea la mejor o peor opción, necesito saberlo.